# Controlling multiple DOMS with Angular Directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm fairly new to angular and I want to create a directive looking like this in AngularJS:

[image]

My approach is to make a template with something like:

progress-bar.html

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="progress-line"></div>
</div>
<div class="current"> 11min </div>
<div class="max"> 24min </div>
```

Then use css to make the graphics and some javascript in the link/compile function of the directive to move the markers ("11min" and "24min") to the right positions, because i don't know the width of the progress-bar beforehand.

Is this a bad approach? I've not found anybody else handling multiple DOMs in one directive.

For testing, I tried to make the container red, when clicked:

```
app.directive('progressBar', function($timeout) {    
    var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on("click", function () {
          element.childNodes[0].css("background-color", "red");
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope:{},
        templateUrl: 'templates/directives/progress-bar.html',
        link: linkFn
    };
});
```

But this doesn't work:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of, don't edit the dom like that

`element.childNodes[0].css("background-color", "red");`

use `ngStyle` thats the `angular way`
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

like so:

```
<div class="container" ng-style="myStyle" ng-click="clickHandler()">
   <div class="progress-line"></div>
</div>
<div class="current"> 11min </div>
<div class="max"> 24min </div>


app.directive('progressBar', function($timeout) {    
    var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.myStyle = {};
        scope.clickHandler = function() { scope.myStyle.background-color = 'red' }
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope:{},
        templateUrl: 'templates/directives/progress-bar.html',
        link: linkFn
    };
});
```

Comment: Okay, but how will I then get the width of the container?

Comment: why do you need the width of the container? just place the progress bar inside the container and calculate the percent

Comment: btw, you might want to look at `bootstrap-ui` https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/  it is a really useful angularjs bootstarp library, which has progress line directives... but if you are dead set on creating your own it is fairly easy

Answer (score 1):

`.css` isn't a native method over DOM, you can use that just by passing DOM to `angular.element`(jQLite).

```
element.children().eq(0).css("background-color", "red");
```

Alternative method would be you could use `ng-style`/`ng-class` directive which can do the same thing.

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for heads up, corrected mine answer :)